# How to test xslt in camel route

Tags: xslt, apache-camel, blueprint-osgi

In my blueprint.xml from direct-vm I receive some xml1

```
<route trace="true" id="someRoute">
            <from uri="direct-vm:someRoute"/>
            <setBody>
                <simple>${body[0]}</simple>
            </setBody>
            //here I have xml1
            <to id="xslt1" uri="xslt:somefile.xsl"/>
            //here I have transformed xml1 to xml2
            <to uri="{{someSite}}"/>
            //here I receive response from someSite in xml3
            <to id="xslt2" uri="xslt:somefile2.xsl"/>//transform it to xml4
            <to uri="direct-vm:service"/>
</route>
```

How can I test every xslt in my route? 
I don't understand how to mock xslt

Comment: Perhaps you should not mock XSLT; In my config I test the XSLT alone  (in/out) but also in the route itself.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood the question, what you want is to test each XSLT transformation in isolation.

In that case, what you need to do is writing some unit tests. I find [Juxy](https://github.com/pavelsher/juxy) really useful for that purpose (have an eye on the 'samples' directory and you'll probably get the grasp in a minute).